# Can someone explain point of TR1 and TR2 in the schematic? (Highlighted in picture)

Tags: motor, driver

[image]

How can there be 40V at the emitter of TR1 across C1 if the secondary of the transformer is 24V?

Comment: 40 volts with respect to where?

Comment: @Andyaka I think it is meant accross C1

Comment: The peak voltage of 24V RMS is around 34V. The transistor circuit is a simple series pass regulator evidenced by the 17.5V notation. The transistors I’d expect to be on a heatsink as they’ll get toasty.

Comment: @Kartman thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain point of TR1 and TR2 in the schematic?

That's the voltage regulator. It's unusual to see it on the negative side, but there's nothing wrong with that.

> How can there be 40V at the emitter of TR1 across C1 if the secondary of the transformer is 24V?

24 Vac generates 24 * sqrt(2) = 34 Vpeak

C1 stores the peak voltage: 34 V.

The "24 V" rating of that transformer is for when it is powered by the nominal AC voltage and it is providing the rated power. Neither of which is the case in your case.

The transformer voltage is unregulated. If the input voltage is on the high end (say 127 Vac instead of 110 Vac) and there is no load (say, the regulator is not working and is off), then that 34 V could easily reach 40 V (that's 17 % higher: nothing unusual).